# (emergency / necessary) services, it triggered a powerful (tsunami / wave)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

My answers are: emergency-  wave

- Earthquakes, storms, floods and droughts are hazards for everybody. Most cities in the world have large populations crowded with bad housing often far from effective (emergency / necessary) services. Between 1990 and 1999, 82 natural catastrophes took place. Thousands of people were killed and economic losses rose to 535 billion dollars.
- A strong earthquake hit Japan on 11 March 2011; it triggered a powerful (tsunami / wave)

Comment: A tsunami is an extremely large wave, so both are correct, but usually you'd want to say tsunami.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct.

The sentence has something missing however, perhaps "and":

> Most cities in the world have large populations crowded with bad housing **and** often far from effective **emergency** services.

Sometimes you will see adjectival phrases with hyphens, which can make it easier to read: "often far-from-effective government/emergency/coastal/whatever services"

To use *necessary*: "... and often lacking necessary services."

This particular event 11 March 2011 was the largest earthquake recorded in Japan, with very many people killed. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_T%C5%8Dhoku_earthquake_and_tsunami#Tsunami) describes it like this:

> The tsunami warning issued by the Japan Meteorological Agency was the most serious on its warning scale; it was rated as a "major tsunami", being at least 3 metres high"

Be clear that *wave* is not incorrect, except that as it was so powerful it is almost universally referred to as *tsunami*.  The wikipedia article explains the characteristics: at sea tsunamis are metres high but hundreds of kilometres wide.